# Как передать неограниченное кол-во аргументов в discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Хочу сделать так, что бы на картинку накладывался текст. Не могу понять как сделать, так, чтобы можно было передать несколько слов. Вот код)

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 

TOKEN = 'tok'

def img(text, name):
    img = Image.open("123.jpg")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("18231.ttf", 100)
    draw.text((1024, 576),text,(255,255,255),font=font)
    img.save(str(name)+".jpg")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='mix ') #инициализируем бота с префиксом 'mix '

@bot.command(pass_context=False) #разрешаем передавать агрументы
async def meme(ctx, *ggwp): #создаем асинхронную фунцию бота
    img(ggwp, "hiq")
    await ctx.send('', file=discord.File('hiq.jpg'))



bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

Все можно, только ты наоборот отсекаешь контекст команды.
`@bot.command(pass_context=True)`
А у вас стоит False.

Comment: Теперь он отправляет сообщения в [таком стиле](https://prnt.sc/qwd105), как сделать так, чтобы он просто пересылал всё, что идёт после resend?